# Flex 3: Timer Won't Stop

Tags: apache-flex, timer

I'm using Flex 3 with Flash 9.

I'm trying to make a timer that will run once after 1 second. Unfortunately, me timer keeps repeating. How do I get it to stop?

```
public var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);


private function visFunc():void {

   myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, imageProducer);
   myTimer.start();

}

private function imageProducer(event:TimerEvent):void {


   var img:Image = new Image;
   img.source = image_path;
   img.x = 56;
   img.y = (tf.y + tf.height + 40);
   radioVBox.addChildAt(img, 0);
   this.height = radioVBox.y + radioVBox.height +110;
   myTimer.stop();
   myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, imageProducer);
}
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: how is visFunc called?  are you sure it isn't being called multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change my code to the following and run some tests, since I don't see any major issues... HOWEVER, if you're not debugging and/or don't have a debugger version of flashplayer running, something may be blowing up on the vbox.addChild line (for example -- null vbox).  If your imageProducer function is cool, then your issue is outside of the 'calling' function.

```
private var myTimer : Timer;

private function visFunc():void
{
    if(myTimer != null) 
    {
        tearDownTimer();
    }

    myTimer = new Timer(1000,1);
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, imageProducer);
    myTimer.start();

}

private function tearDownTimer():void
{
    if(myTimer) 
    {
        myTimer.stop();
        myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, imageProducer);
        myTimer = null;
    }
}


private function imageProducer(event:TimerEvent):void
{
   var img:Image = new Image();
   img.source = image_path;
   img.x = 56;
   img.y = (tf.y + tf.height + 40);
   radioVBox.addChildAt(img, 0);
   this.height = radioVBox.y + radioVBox.height +110;

   tearDownTimer();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thank you very much for the help. I made a really stupid error. I was inadvertently calling the visFunc function multiple times. Again, thanks for the help.